# Is it bad practice to use unregistered html elements for semantic purposes?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, web-component

I want to use unregistered web components for styling and semantic purposes. For example, I might use the tag `<t-card></t-card>`, without it being registered using `customElements.define`. The browser and stylesheets don't seem to have any problems with this either, but I've noticed issues with 3rd-party-libraries such as Vue.js.

So should I do this or just stick to the `<div class="card"></div>` style? I'm also developing for any modern browsers, so backwards compatability is not an issue.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. It might only be semantic to you, but the browser will just treat them like `<div>` elements.

Comment: The browser certainly makes a distinction between **undefined elements** and DIVs (defined element). You can target them with the ``:defined`` or ``:not(:defined)`` Pseudo selector [MDN :defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:defined). If you want semantic content that is **not** displayed/processed as DOM content I would suggest a ``<template>`` [MDN Template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) or a Custom Element with only a shadowDOM to keep Vue happy???

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `vue.js` this is certainly be a bad practice because in `vue` custom tags are always an imported component which is registered locally or globally. Also, say that you are working with team of `vue` developer and they have no idea where the hell `t-card` component file is located?

Comment: I see how that would be a problem. Even though I can add this element to ignoredElements it still might be confusing to some.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good coding practice. It is confusing for others and also it "hides" information. For example if there is a class called "card", you know that you (can) have multiple elements with that class. If the id is "card" you know that there can be only one element. If you do `<t-card></t-card>` you don't know that.

Comment: I don't think this argument applys here really, since you could argue the same for registered web components.